# Python error: TypeError: Expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, nltk, typeerror, sentiment-analysis, nltokenizer

I'm currently working on a sentiment analysis project using nltk in python. I can't get my script to pass in rows of text from my csv to perform tokenization on. However, if I pass the text in one entry at a time it works fine. I am getting one persistent error: 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object' when I try and pass the whole csv in.
Here is the printed data frame and python code I'm using. Any help to resolve this issue would be great.

```
                              abstract
0    Allergic diseases are often triggered by envir...
1    omal lymphopoietin (TSLP) has important roles ...
2    of atrial premature beats, and a TSLP was high...
3     deposition may play an important role in the ...
4    ted by TsPLP was higher than that mediated by ...
5    nal Stat5 transcription factor in that TSLP st...
```

```
data = pd.read_csv('text.csv', sep=';', encoding = 'utf-8')
x = data.loc[:, 'abstract']
print(x.head())
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(x)
print(tokens)
```

Attached is the full stack trace error. 
EDIT: print statement

[image]

EDIT: Output

[image]

Comment: Which line gives you that error?

Comment: Please update your question with the full Traceback message.

Comment: `tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(x)` is the reason of error. Here x is a df. You must pass `String` in `nltk.word_tokenize()` function. One thing you can do, you can iterate over x and pass the each line of string in  `nltk.word_tokenize()`

Comment: @0buz Sorry should have clarified it's this line: tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(x)

Comment: @quamrana I have updated the question with a link to the full stack trace error

Comment: You can use `tokens = [nltk.word_tokenize(line) for line in x ]` something like this

Comment: @Ta_Req Ah thanks! I'll give it a go shortly! Looks like it should do the trick, just looking for a way I can tokenize multiple sets of text quickly without entering by hand.

Comment: No, don't *attach* a list. Update the question with the full **text** of the Traceback message. You had the text right in front of you.

Answer (score 1):

tokens = [nltk.word_tokenize(line) for line in x ]

Comment: Thanks this worked! So the input text is formatted in csv, so one bit of text per cell, so how can I make sure that the output from this is printed by cell, not just as one block of text?

Comment: I do not understand. If you write the expected output I can have a look.

Comment: There are multiple entries in the csv file, the script you suggested tokenizes them however the output is printed as one block of text with no delimiters. It would be very helpful if I could get each cell of text in the csv returned like so: "Allergic', 'diseases', 'are', 'often', 'triggered', 'by', 'environmental', 'allergens', 'that', 'induce', 'dominant', 'type', '2', 'immune', 'responses', ',', 'characterized', 'by', 'the', 'infiltrated', 'T-helper', 'type', '2', '(', 'TH2', ')', 'lymphocytes', ',', 'eosinophils']        Then followed by the next entry and so on with **clear separations**

Comment: You can follow the answer by @0buz. Concatenate the lines in to a big text and then tokenize

Comment: I think the solution I suggested must return each cell content with separation. e. g . `[ [first cell tokens],[second cel token], [third cell token][...],.,.,]`

Comment: your solution works but returns the entire contents of the input file as tokens. I'm looking for a means to return one set of tokens per abstract with clear separation. At the moment I just have a massive block of returned tokens

Comment: I am sure massive block of tokens because of large abstract. You can print the cell item and check how output is organised. e. g. `token_of_first_cell = tokens[0] ` , `token_of_second_cell = tokens[1]`

Answer (score 1):

The [nltk documentation](https://www.nltk.org/index.html?highlight=word_tokenize) give an example of `nltk.word_tokenize` usage where you may notice "sentence" is a `string`.

In your situation, `x` is a dataframe `Series`(of strings), which you need to reconstruct into a string before passing it to `nltk.word_tokenize`.

One way to deal with this is to create your `nltk` "sentence" from `x`:

```
x = data.loc[:, 'abstract']
sentence=' '.join(x)
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
```

**EDIT:**
Try this as per further comments (remember this will be a `Series` of tokens to be accessed accordingly):

```
tokens=x.apply(lambda sentence: nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))
```

Comment: So do you want one set of tokens per abstract cell?

Comment: Is there anyway to de-construct it back into a series of strings after it has been tokenized? Thanks

Comment: Yes that would be perfect!

Comment: Please see my EDIT and let me know how it goes.

Comment: just tried your edit and it works but weirdly only half way through the text. Phenotypic analysis of these cells revealed that they are at the pro-B cell stage of differentiation and express cell surface markers characteristic of pro-B cells cultured in IL-7. TSLP can replace the activity of IL-7 in supporting the progression of B lymphocytes from uncommitted bipotential precursors. In the absence of either TSLP or IL-7, the progeny of cells that give rise to mature B lymphocytes fail to develop from these bipotential precursors. [To, examine, the, role, of, gamma, c, in,] ...

Comment: Difficult to help without knowing what error or behavior you get, and where. Try debugging the line you suspect fails i.e. copy the text into a variable and do a tokenization for just that variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209790/discussion-between-benedict-groves-and-0buz).